# How to submit a fancybox form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox to open submitted form like this:

```
<form name="form" id="myForm" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=abc" method="post" target="iframe" onsubmit="document.getElementById('iframe').src='{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=abc';">    
<input type="hidden" name="xyz" value="123">
<input type="submit" value="REGISTER" id="button" class="button">
</form> 

                $("#button").click(function() {                                            
                $("#iframe").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'transitionIn'      : 'fadeIn',
                'transitionOut'     : 'fadeOut'
                }).click();                            
            });
```

with `<input type="submit" value="REGISTER" id="button" class="button">` everything is

working fine. but for some reason i need to use `<a href="">REGISTER</a>`. So I tried

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">REGISTER</a>
```

&

```
<a href="javascript:document.form.submit();">REGISTER</a>
```

In above cases fancybox is popping out but my form is not getting submitted.

How do I submit my form successfully within click function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your link like this:

```
<a href="#" id="submit_link">REGISTER</a>
```

And use this code:

```
$(function(){
  $('#submit_link').click(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
    return false;
  });
});
```