# Submit form data to iframe FancyBox (or Modal?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, python-2.7, iframe

I have to make a digital scrum board using python. As framework I'm using Django.

Right now I'm struggling with passing data to a FancyBox `iframe`. My idea is to use a `<form>` with hidden fields, if I submit the form it should post the data to the `iframe`.

The `iframe` contains another form, which must have the values submitted by the other form.

I have a table containing columns, the table and the columns have ids where the table id is unique and the column ids are not, if I want to add a item, the table and column id should be passed to a create form (which is inside the iframe).

This is how my first form looks like:

```
<form id="createtask" method="get" action="{% url "create_task" board.id column.id %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <input class="hidden" name="column_id" id="column_{{ column.id }}" value="{{ column.id }}">
    <input class="hidden" name="board_id" id="board_{{ board.id }}" value="{{ board.id }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

I know that im using `get` instead of `post`, the reason why I did that this is the second option from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6006375).

The answer contains following jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#createtask").submit(function() {
        $form = $(this);
        $.fancybox({
                'title': "form submission",
                'href': $form.attr("action") + "?" + $form.serialize(),
                'type': 'iframe'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The problem is that the data is passed, but instead inside a `iframe` it loads a new page with the content I want inside the `iframe`.

If I use

`<a href={% url "create_task" board.id column.id %}>`

instead of

`<input type="submit" value="Create">`

the form isn't submitted but the form inside the `iframe` is loaded like it should.

My questions are, is there any solution to pass the data to the iframe?
Is there a more Django/Python way doing this?
Would it help me to use a bootstrap modal instead of an `iframe`?

### EDIT:

rcadhikaris answer is a good, but its only a workaround.

Using jQuery to read out the data from the `parent.document` made me not use the form at all but the question is still how to submit form data to an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `data-` tags and fetch it from iframe using jQuery.

Comment: sry but I am really inexperienced with jQuery and I'm not sure what you are talking about if you say `data-` tags

Comment: well I searched it up. Silly me its not even jQuery. I can try it ofcourse but I'm not sure right now how to handle the data with jQuery inside the iframe

Comment: Even though I could achieve what I wanted to do, this isn't the answer for the Question. It really helped me and everything is working. But this is just a workaround and not a solution.