# Get Preview with Fancybox and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I am trying to use a form to populate a fancybox. Essentially, I am using the "get" method to pass data to a url that will populate google map data in the fancybox. Basically, a user enters city, and it populates to mysite.com/city in the fancybox). I can't even get the fancybox to load.

I am using fancybox 1.3.4

Below is my current code:

```
<form id="form" class="form" method="get">
<label for="search">City:</label>
<input type="text" name="search" maxlength="50" size="30" />
</form>
<a class="form" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="URL" id="datacity">Go</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.datacity').on("click", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  url: this.href,
  data: $("#form").serializeArray(), // NOTE:I REALIZE IM NOT PASSING A URL PARAMENTER-- Id like it to add href.FORMDATA. and display that in an iframe (below)
  success: function (data) {
    $.fancybox(data, {
      fitToView: false,
      width: 905,
      height: 505,
      autoSize: false,
      closeClick: false,
      openEffect: 'none',
      closeEffect: 'none'
    }); 
     } 
   }); 
 }); 
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery? Do you get an JavaScript errors in your console?

Comment: i have loaded jQuery with no javascript errors

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: It could be an incompatibility issue. I ran into errors using jQuery 2.x with FancyBox 1.3.4. Had to revert to jQuery 1.8.3. Maybe 1.4.2 is too old.

Comment: unfortunately im locked into 1.4.2. it should be possible to do-- just not sure how. ive found im not the only one with this problem. :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427289/need-help-with-this-fancybox-form-submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem with a simpler solution-- no need to convert the form to ajax

```
$(function() {

$("#form").submit(function() {

    $form = $(this);

    $.fancybox({
            'href': $form.attr("action") + "?" + $form.serialize(),
            'type': 'iframe'
    });

    return false;

});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample code, I believe you should be selecting `datacity` as an ID rather than a CLASS.

In its current form, the jQuery selection fails and the default behavior of the `<a href>` is performed instead of your jQuery code.

To select this:

```
<a class="form" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="URL" id="datacity">Go</a>
```

use this:

```
$('#datacity').on("click", function (e) {
```

instead of this:

```
$('.datacity').on("click", function (e) {
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion-- made the change. but it still fails unfortunately.